# CustomTableModel + JTable = table isn't filled

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, jtable, tablemodel

I'm trying to implement my own table model to show the schedule in JTable. I implemented it, but table even isn't filled. Maybe I lost some methods which are required to be implemented? Here is my code:

```
public class ScheduleTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private ArrayList<TimeInterval> timeIntervals;
    private ArrayList<Day> days;
    private LinkedHashMap<ScheduleSlot, Lesson> fullSchedule;
    private LinkedHashMap<ScheduleSlot, Lesson> partialSchedule;
    private ScheduleType scheduleType;


    public ScheduleTableModel(ArrayList<TimeInterval> timeIntervals, ArrayList<Day> days, LinkedHashMap<ScheduleSlot, Lesson> fullSchedule, LinkedHashMap<ScheduleSlot, Lesson> partialSchedule) {
        this.timeIntervals = timeIntervals;
        this.days = days;
        this.fullSchedule = fullSchedule;
        this.partialSchedule = partialSchedule;
        this.scheduleType = ScheduleType.PARTIAL;
        fireTableStructureChanged();
    }

    public ScheduleTableModel(LinkedHashMap<ScheduleSlot, Lesson> fullSchedule) {
        this.fullSchedule = fullSchedule;
        this.scheduleType = ScheduleType.GENERAL;
        fireTableStructureChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        if (scheduleType == ScheduleType.PARTIAL) {
            return timeIntervals.size() + 1;
        } else {
            return fullSchedule.size();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        if (scheduleType == ScheduleType.PARTIAL) {
            return days.size() + 1;
        } else {
            return 3;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        if (scheduleType == ScheduleType.PARTIAL) {
            if (columnIndex > 0 && rowIndex > 0) {
                for (Map.Entry<ScheduleSlot, Lesson> entry : partialSchedule.entrySet()) {
                    if (entry.getKey().getDay().equals(getColumnDay(columnIndex)) && entry.getKey().getTime().equals(getRowTimeInterval(rowIndex))) {
                        return entry;
                    }
                }
            } else if (rowIndex == 0 && columnIndex > 0) {
                return days.get(columnIndex);
            } else if (columnIndex == 0 && rowIndex > 0) {
                return timeIntervals.get(rowIndex);
            } else if (rowIndex == 0 && columnIndex == 0) {
                return "";
            }
        } else {
            List<Map.Entry<ScheduleSlot, Lesson>> scheduleIterator = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<ScheduleSlot, Lesson>>(fullSchedule.entrySet());
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0: {
                    scheduleIterator.get(columnIndex).getKey().getTimeSlot();
                }
                case 1: {
                    scheduleIterator.get(columnIndex).getKey().getPlaceSlot();
                }
                case 2: {
                    scheduleIterator.get(columnIndex).getValue();
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return false;
    }

    public Day getColumnDay(int columnIndex) {
        return (Day) getValueAt(0, columnIndex);
    }

    public TimeInterval getRowTimeInterval(int rowIndex) {
        return (TimeInterval) getValueAt(rowIndex, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        if (scheduleType == ScheduleType.GENERAL) {
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0: {
                    return fullSchedule.entrySet().iterator().next().getKey().getTimeSlot().getClass();
                }
                case 1: {
                    return fullSchedule.entrySet().iterator().next().getKey().getPlaceSlot().getClass();
                }
                case 2: {
                    return fullSchedule.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue().getGroup().getClass();
                }
                case 3: {
                    return fullSchedule.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue().getProfessor().getClass();
                }
                case 4: {
                    return fullSchedule.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue().getCourse().getClass();
                }

            }
        } else {
            return String.class;
        }
        return String.class;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        if (scheduleType == ScheduleType.GENERAL) {
            switch (column) {
                case 0: {
                    return "";
                }
                case 1: {
                    return "";
                }
                case 2: {
                    return "";
                }
                case 3: {
                    return "";
                }
                case 4: {
                    return "";
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Could anybody point me on my mistakes? Thanks everyone in advance!

p.s. I'm not sure if it is necessary to implement setValueAt for Jtable be filled. If I'm right and it is necessary could you show an example of the implementation of this method?

### ADDITION:

Implemented setValueAt(), but nothing changed:

```
@Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        if (scheduleType == ScheduleType.PARTIAL) {
            Map.Entry<ScheduleSlot, Lesson> entry = (Map.Entry<ScheduleSlot, Lesson>) aValue;
            if (columnIndex > 0 && rowIndex > 0) {
                Day day = getColumnDay(columnIndex);
                TimeInterval timeInterval = getRowTimeInterval(rowIndex);
                TimeInterval entryInterval = entry.getKey().getTime();
                Day entryDay = entry.getKey().getDay();
                if (day.equals(entryDay) && timeInterval.equals(entryInterval)) {
                    fullSchedule.put(new ScheduleSlot(new TimeSlot(entry.getKey().getTime(), entry.getKey().getDay()),
                            new PlaceSlot(entry.getKey().getRoom(), entry.getKey().getBuilding())), entry.getValue());
                }
            } else if (rowIndex == 0 && columnIndex > 0) {
                days.add((Day) aValue);
            } else if (columnIndex == 0 && rowIndex > 0) {
                timeIntervals.add((TimeInterval) aValue);
            }
        }

        fireTableDataChanged();
    }
```

Here is the picture of tablemodel structure how I see it:

[image]

I wanna yellow part be filled from `timeIntervals` list, green part - from `days` list and the purpule part - from `partialSchedule` hashmap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- your `AbstractTableModel` missing [important setXxx() method(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10616768/714968)
- why did you use too hard methods `fireTableStructureChanged();` [use proper fireXxxXxx()methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6901508/714968), this code example contains most of important methods for `AbstractTableModel` with proper `fireXxxXxx()`
- I'd be use `DefaultTableModel` based on `Vector<Vector<Object>>` rather than `XxxMap` or `XxxHashMap`, this way required depest knowledge about `JTable`, `XxxTableModel` and `XxxMap` or `XxxHashMap` works together

Comment: Are talking about setValueAt() method? I implemented it, but it seems nothing changed :( Could you please look at my implementation. I suspect that I missing something, which is necessary for data to be filled in table. p.s. Don't pay attention to `fireTableStructureChanged();`, I'm just put it there to be sure that table is show what it contains.

Comment: ah, sorry for my dullness. I just forgot to add scroll pane to the frame. Thank you very much!