# Adding a button in JTable - Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I want to add button in JTable. I have made its Renderer and cellEditor class but i just can't figure out where to place the button in my code/ in netbeans...

SupplierForm.java

```
public class SupplierForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form SupplierForm
     */
    public SupplierForm() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        supplierCombo = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        dataTable = new javax.swing.JTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));

        supplierCombo.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Item 1", "USER", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));
        supplierCombo.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                supplierComboActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        dataTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "ID", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ));
       /*This is giving error
       dataTable.getColumn("Button").setCellRenderer(new ButtonRenderer());
        dataTable.getColumn("Button").setCellEditor(
            new ButtonEditor(new JCheckBox()));*/
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(dataTable);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(173, 173, 173)
                .addComponent(supplierCombo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 141, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 660, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(89, 89, 89))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(supplierCombo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(34, 34, 34))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void supplierComboActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        String tableName = (String) supplierCombo.getModel().getSelectedItem();
         DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) dataTable.getModel();
         int c = model.getRowCount();
         for (int i=c-1; i>=0; i--){
            model.removeRow(i);
            dataTable.revalidate();
            }
        String sql = "select * from "+ tableName+"  ";
        try {
            try {
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SupplierForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            Connection connect = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\Merlin1.accdb");
            Statement statmnt = connect.createStatement();
            ResultSet rslt = statmnt.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rslt.next()){
                String id = rslt.getString("ID");
                String name = rslt.getString("USER_NAME");
                String surname = rslt.getString("PASSWORD");
                //String age = rslt.getString("Age");
                model.addRow(new Object[]{id,name,surname});

            }

        } catch(SQLException e){
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"No Supplier exists with this name");

            }
    // dataTable.revalidate();

    }                                             

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*
         * Set the Nimbus look and feel
         */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
         * default look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SupplierForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SupplierForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SupplierForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SupplierForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /*
         * Create and display the form
         */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new SupplierForm().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JTable dataTable;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox supplierCombo;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

ButtonEditor.java

```
 class ButtonEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
  protected JButton button;

  private String label;

  private boolean isPushed;

  public ButtonEditor(JCheckBox checkBox) {
    super(checkBox);
    button = new JButton();
    button.setOpaque(true);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        fireEditingStopped();
      }
    });
  }

  public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable dataTable, Object value,
      boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
    if (isSelected) {
      button.setForeground(dataTable.getSelectionForeground());
      button.setBackground(dataTable.getSelectionBackground());
    } else {
      button.setForeground(dataTable.getForeground());
      button.setBackground(dataTable.getBackground());
    }
    label = (value == null) ? "" : value.toString();
    button.setText(label);
    isPushed = true;
    return button;
  }

  public Object getCellEditorValue() {
    if (isPushed) {
      // 
      // 
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(button, label + ": Ouch!");
      // System.out.println(label + ": Ouch!");
    }
    isPushed = false;
    return new String(label);
  }

  public boolean stopCellEditing() {
    isPushed = false;
    return super.stopCellEditing();
  }

  protected void fireEditingStopped() {
    super.fireEditingStopped();
  }
}
```

ButtonRenderer.java

```
public class ButtonRenderer extends JButton implements TableCellRenderer{
     public ButtonRenderer() {
    setOpaque(true);
  }

  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable dataTable, Object value,
      boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    if (isSelected) {
      setForeground(dataTable.getSelectionForeground());
      setBackground(dataTable.getSelectionBackground());
    } else {
      setForeground(dataTable.getForeground());
      setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
    }
    setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
    return this;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

- not easy job to create `TableCellRenderer` and `TableCellEditor` for [Buttons Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and `JSpinner` too, fo example for `RadioButtonGroup` I'm using `JComboBox` as `TableCellEditor` (sure with `JRadioButtons` as `TableCellRenderer`) rather than [JRadioButtons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10616768/714968),
- no way, use [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) by @camickr instead

Comment: Indeed not an easy job ...therefore, windows form rules